# Convert existing .NET assembly to Windows Runtime Component Library?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

How can I change an existing project to build as a Windows Runtime Component library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Install the VS Commands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a83505c6-77b3-44a6-b53b-73d77cba84c8)

IT has an [option](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/blog) that

> Convert To Portable Class Library
>
> It is now possible to convert C# class libraries to a Portable Class
>   Libraries. Option is available from context menu on C# class library
>   projects.

You simply right click over the project file and select 'Convert to Portable Library'.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the project type.  If it's a Class Library, you can go to Project->Properties->Application Tab and choose "Windows Runtime Component" under "Output Type".

[image]